# I keep on getting an error 13 type mismatch error, How can I get it out?

Tags: ms-access, search, vba, type-mismatch

In Access 2010 I am trying to create a search box for a table of contacts on a form.

Here is my code:

```vb
Private Sub Command119_Click()
On Error GoTo Command119_Click_Err

If (Eval("[Forms]![frmTitlePage]![SearchBox] Is Null")) Then
    ' Clear Filter when search box empty
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRemoveFilterSort
End If
' Handle "'s in search
TempVars.Add "strSearch", Replace(Forms!frmTitlePage!SearchBox, """", """""")
' Build the Filter
TempVars.Add "strFilter", "([Last Name] Like "" * " & [TempVars]![strSearch] & " * "" )"
TempVars.Add "strFilter", TempVars!strFilter & " OR ([First Name] Like "" * " & [TempVars]![strSearch] & " * "" )"
DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", TempVars!strFilter, ""
TempVars.Remove "strFilter"
TempVars.Remove "strSearch"


Command119_Click_Exit:
Exit Sub

Command119_Click_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume Command119_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

I am obviously horrible at this coding so any additional help to clean this search tool up would help tremendously.

Comment: Why are you evaluating a form control? I reckon you are going to run into problems with names with single quotes (D'Arcy). You should consider the filter properties of your form rather than `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRemoveFilterSort` ... to start with :)

Comment: What is TempVars and where does it come from?

Comment: I used the code from the Access Contacts Template and tried to mold it into my search box. How could I use the DoCmd.RunCommandacCmdRemoveFilterSort that you suggest?

Comment: I need to know what tempvars is and where it is created.

Comment: Tempvars sets a temporary variable with a given value. It is what the template used. In object browser it is in the class "Application"

Comment: Have you got a link to this template? To me, the whole thing is far too complicated, I would use something much simpler. Are you trying to learn or do you just want to allow people to search in contacts by surname and forename? How many people are in the list?

Comment: To get the template, in access, go to file>new>contacts>contacts(the one in the middle). What I did was copied the search bar they have on the top of the page into my form. What I want to happen is when someone types a first or last name in the box and press the button, the contacts information pops up in their allotted paces that I have  put on a form.

Comment: What would be the simpler way? I have very little knowledge in programming and thought that a search bar was something I was capable of doing but I keep on running across errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have some extra spaces in your search

Your original code produced `Like " * Smith * "`

remove the extra spaces around the place you add `[TempVars]![strSearch]` to produce this:

```
TempVars.Add "strFilter", "([Last Name] Like ""*" & [TempVars]![strSearch] & "*"" )"
TempVars.Add "strFilter", TempVars!strFilter & " OR ([First Name] Like ""*" & [TempVars]![strSearch] & "*"" )"
```

should now produce `Like "*Smith*"`

Comment: I did what you said but unfortunately, I received a syntax error.